# Installing "listings" in mac for R sweave

Tags: listings, installing, mac, sweave

I am trying to install the package "listings" so I can show python code on LaTeX, with R sweave.

I found the folder `/Library` and the only thing LaTeX related I found there is a folder called `/TeX` I don't know how to go on.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? If you installed TeX Live via MacTeX the listings package is already there. Did you try to use it?

Comment: How can I know what distribution I am using? I know I have installed MacTex to see if "listings" became available, but it didn't.

Comment: Garcia Companys: Please run the commands `kpsewhich listings.sty` and `which pdflatex` in Terminal and let us know the information returned.

Comment: @HerbSchulz for which pdflatex I am getting: /usr/local/bin/pdflatex

Comment: nothing shown for kpsewhich listings.sty

Comment: You did not install MacTeX. You may have installed MikTeX but I have no experience with that distribution or how to update/install packages with it. Sorry.

Comment: I have installed MacTex, why it does not appear?

Comment: You might use have also installed something else. If you run `which -a pdflatex` you should get a list of all pdflatex programs in you path. What does it return?

Comment: I get these two:

/usr/local/bin/pdflatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex

Comment: Can you uninstall the version that has programs/links in /usr/local/bin? If you are going to use a front-end, e.g., TeXShop, it can be (TeXShop is) set up to use the TeX Live distribution binaries in /Library/TeX/texbin.

Comment: It is strangely working now, I am not sure of what did I do